# plot line chart, regardless the order of x axis python

Tags: python, plotly, linechart, plotly-python, plotly-express

i have a dataframe with two columns. MachineID and Value. I sort the dataframe to descending order(machines with high values first) and plot the line chart. But still, it shows the x axis(MachineID 1 to 60, rather than taking the highest values MachineID first.)

To solve this error, changed the machineID column to string but still couldn't get the machines with High values first.

Sample dataframe:

```
MachineID   Value
    33     6.962754
    16     6.955913
    44     6.722355
    31     6.320854
    1      6.243701
    9      5.894093
```

Mycode:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(data, x="MachineID", y="Values")
fig.show()
```

Output for above code:

[image]

Required Output:

Machines with high values first and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a **line plot** and show the machine with the **highest value first**, you have to:

- sort your df on highest value
- and tell plotly to view the x-axes with the machine id's as a categorical axis by **using `fig.update_xaxes(type='category')`**

**Example code:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
    
data = {
    'MachineID': {0: 33, 1: 16, 2: 44, 3: 31, 4: 1, 5: 9},
    'Value': {0: 6.962754, 1: 6.955913, 2: 6.722355, 
              3: 6.320854, 4: 6.243701, 5: 5.894093},
}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
# sort your df on highest value, descending  
df = df.sort_values(by='Value', ascending=False)
    
fig = px.line(df, x='MachineID', y='Value')

# set x-axis as categorical:
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
```

**Resulting plot:**

[image: categorical x-axis line plot, highest value first]

You can find **more info** on categorical axes here:
https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/